# please help me to convert ['1,7'] into [1,7] using python

Tags: python, list

I tried with this

```
test_list = ['1,7'] 
test_list = [int(i) for i in test_list]
```

got this error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,7'
```

Comment: `["1,7"]` is a list containing a single string. You need to split that string on `","` in order to separate the two values.

Comment: `[int(j) for i in ['1,7'] for j in i.split(',')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
test_list = [int(i) for i in test_list]
```

is iterating through each string in your test_list, not each number. So you first need to point to the string of numbers, and then the numbers within the string. The long route, for better understanding, would be:

```
new = []

for i in test_list: # pointing to the '1,7' string
    for j in i.split(','): # splitting that string into a list
        new.append(int(j)) # appending each split as an int into the new list

print(new) # returns: [1, 7]
```

More info on the split() method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp).

The shorter method, as Epsi95 has already said, is using a method know as "list comprehension", more info on that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp). It's the same implementation as the for loops above, just neater and more efficient (and a lot prettier):

```
new = [int(j) for i in ['1,7'] for j in i.split(',')]
```